# Module "PlayRawPlugIn" is not installed

Tags: qt, plugins, qml, qmake

I'm trying to integrate a QML Plugin in a qt project but I get: module "PlayRawPlugIn" is not installed import PlayRawPlugIn 1.0

The structure of my application is:

```
player.pro
--playerInterface.pro
--PlayRawPlugIn.pro
```

player.pro

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
CONFIG += ORDERED
SUBDIRS += playerInterface
SUBDIRS += playrawplugin
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Many thanks!!

Comment: Hi, if you need your `playRawPlugIn` in your `playerInterface`, you should put it before `playerInterface` in your pro file. Keyword `CONFIG = ordered` means you want to compile subdirs in the order they are mentionned in your pro file.

Comment: I just tried this but unfortunately I get the same error.

Comment: I hope you didn't forget to run qmake again ? Hum I suppose this plugin compile well alone ? And you playerInterface too if you remove PlayRawPlugIn dependencies ?

Comment: I had run qmake again. The plugin and the playerInterface runs perfect alone. I built them separately and now I'm trying to put them together

Comment: I solved the problem. playrawplugin folder should be inside playerInterface folder